# Windows batch script - parse and expand the variable to pass as a string to external program?

Tags: r, windows, batch-file, command-line

I want to use a relative file path as a command line argument but as the example and assessment below will demonstrate, the variable passes `\..\` as a string, it doesn't evaluate it.

Can I can force the command line to parse and expand the variable as a string?

```
: For example:  I have a R script file I want to launch from the command line:

Set RPath=C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.0\bin\Rscript.exe
SET RScript=%CD%\..\..\HCF_v9.R

SET SourceFile=%CD%\..\Source\

ECHO String used for Source Location - %SourceFile%

"%RPath%" "%RScript%" %SourceFile%
```

The inclusion of `\..\` works in the call to R as an external program because the batch file can resolve it's own commands.

The variable of SourceFile however doesn't work because the SourceFile variable hasn't expanded `\..\`, it has just included it as part of the string and R can't process `\..\`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `for` replaceable parameters to resolve to the real path

```
for %%a in ("..\..\HCF_v9.R") do set "RScript=%%~fa"
```

Answer (score 1):

@MC ND has provided the batch file approach; an R-centric approach would be to pass the current directory to R, and modify it there.

```
; batch file
Set RPath=C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.0\bin\Rscript.exe
SET RScript=%CD%\..\..\HCF_v9.R
"%RPath%" "%RScript%" %CD%


# in R
srcpath <- commandArgs(TRUE)[1]
srcpath <- normalizePath(file.path(srcpath, "../Source"))
```